# Create new entry when relation attribute is updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm building a small practice app and have gotten stuck. I have these models in a one to many relationship:

Ticket:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :descriptions
end
```

Description:

```
class Description < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :ticket
end
```

The purpose of the relationship is so that each time you update/edit a ticket's description (only if the description has changed from the previous), a new description entry is created. This gives me the ability to have a history of previous descriptions of that ticket. Description is a string that will be a text field in the ticket new and edit views.

I'm having trouble implementing this. I know I most likely have to change the code in the tickets controller and descriptions controller, but I'm not sure how. I'm also not sure how to implement the ticket views. Thanks for helping me learn Rails.

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Also, what you're trying to do *(yes, I understand you're learning, but it's worth pointing out)* can be accomplished through the popular **[paper_trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail)** gem.

Comment: The question is how to implement the functionality explained. I would be inclined to use paper_trail, but I only need to version this one attribute, and learning how to do something like this would be beneficial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you would have to add nested Description attributes to your Ticket form

Here is a good write up to use accepts_nested_attributes_for:
http://rubysource.com/complex-rails-forms-with-nested-attributes/

And a railscasts video:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely what I was looking for. I'm trying to implement it now.